# why do people access stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, usability

**Does Stack Overflow really help other programmers or is it just meant for making reputation to impress each other.**

Why do people abuse or down-vote questions or answers **(rather than improving them)** ?

Why do people say harsh words to each other ?

Programmers come here to find solutions, not for fun.

Comment: thanks for downvote guys...you rocks...

Comment: i dont know why they suspended it...i didnt do anything....

Comment: "Inspire"? No, see you have it all wrong. Voting is not personal, it should be based solely on the content on the post.

Comment: @Austin henley post this to answered list i strongly accept it.

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa.  I don't know about you or anyone else, but *I* definitely have fun when I'm here.  I also find solutions.  That is also very important.

Comment: yah its fun here but we dont need to make people guild on asking or posting answer or question..

Comment: because every one has started from nothing and i m bet they reach well reputed status not without anyone help...i know sometime its needed to say hard words to make people realize about their mistake but not everytime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears you have been having a bad experience on the site. Don't let those small number of users affect your experience.

> Why do people abuse or down-vote questions or answer (rather they can inspire them) ?

Voting is not personal, it should be based solely on the content on the post. As far as inspiring them goes, you can always help them improve the quality of their posts by commenting.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's (please don't hate me..) like any other online community and website.

You'll have people that come here for it's purest purpose, for knowledge and gettings answers for questions

But you'll also have the people that use it as a *game* and for fun. I enjoy the "points" aspect.

You'll have losers who enjoy trolling and being mean.

and you'll have really inspirational members too.

My question in response would be, `Do the creators want this site to be thought of as more fun, or more educational?`

---

`thanks for downvote guys...you rocks... – Dipesh Parmar 19 secs ago`

Don't expect friendly customer service if you yell at the person on the phone. same principle here.

Comment: Taking down someone who is already pretty frustrated is not nice or helpful at all